# Atmel SAM3X8E (cortex M3) MPU confusion

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, cortex-m, cortex-m3

The SAM3X8E has a MPU, what I am confused about is how to combine both SRAM and FLASH into the same protected memory region since they live at different contiguous region addresses.

Is this possible?

I am interested in implementing a custom bootloader/system recovery code which would keep a little bit of ram I want to remain protected from potentially broken user uploaded code.

Comment: this is covered in the arm documentation.

Comment: I and D are both mentioned, for cortex-ms there are defined (read the arm docs) address spaces for I and D and peripherals.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, my understanding from the docs is the regions are contiguous, meaning what I want is not possible. But I wanted to check.

Comment: that would be pretty useless for arm to design such a thing.  no cortex-m designs are expected to have instruction and data regions touch, that would be an extremely rare design.

Comment: It is not the best written documentation, arm usually does a better job, but it does appear to  describe what you need.

Comment: it wont boot there of course, if the users messes with the flash then it is game over on the next reset.

Comment: now you cannot remap addresses it is all physical as stated in the arm docs.  but for protecting regions you dont need them to be contiguous...you can overlap regions as needed and the highest priority one wins in that case as documented, but for protecting some of your code there appears to be a mechanism including a privileged mode.